# Catch View in Landscape Mode

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

In my view there are buttons on bottom of the view, I change the button position  for 4inch and 3.5 inch but for landscape mode buttons stay below the view, I want to catch view in landscape mode so I can write new code for button position ,

How can I catch the view in landscape mode.? I've tried a lot of code, None of it did not work.

My initial view is UINavigationView , 
Here is my code;

```
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
{
    CGRect screenBounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    if (screenBounds.size.height == 568)
    {


    //do below if it is portrait
        buttonnewreg.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, self.view.frame.size.height - 2, 320.0, 46.0);
        buttonadminreq.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, self.view.frame.size.height  + 42, 320.0, 46.0);

    //do something if it is landscape 
           ???

    }

}
```

I need if statements

Thanx

Comment: It helps if you show the code you tried, even if it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
 -(void)viewDidLoad
{

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(orientationChanged)
                                                 name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification
                                               object:nil];

}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];

}

-(void)orientationChanged
{
   //Handle OrientationChange
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Register for orientation change notifications and/or implement orientation handling methods and reposition your buttons there.

Have a look in UIKit Function Reference at the function **UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape**

An example of how it may be used, assuming the implementation of two methods,  *doLandscapeStuff* and *doPortraitStuff*.

```
// get the device orientation
UIDeviceOrientation orientation = [UIDevice currentDevice].orientation;
// conditional for device orientation
(UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape(orientation)) ? [self doLandscapeStuff] :
                                                [self doPortraitStuff];
```

And because you said "I need if statements" change to this

```
// get the device orientation
UIDeviceOrientation orientation = [UIDevice currentDevice].orientation;

// conditional for device orientation
if (UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape(orientation)) {

     // do landscape stuff here...

}
```